# Print AWK ou GREP in table format

Tags: awk, text-formatting

How can I organize a command to print the results like this:

```
USER   | PACKAGE | CREATOR
result -  result - result
result -  result - result
result -  result - result
```

I want to fetch these results from a file: /usr/local/users/*/user.conf

There are several files of different users, for example:

```
/usr/local/users/user1/user.conf
/usr/local/users/user2/user.conf
/usr/local/users/user3/user.conf
...
```

I'm using the wildcard character, because there are a lot of files, so I need to organize the display in tables.

He's got the content that way.

```
username=test
package=basic
creator=admin
```

I tried it that way, just to try to fetch a variable, but I don't know how to complement the command.

```
grep package /usr/local/users/*/user.conf
```

Comment: Is there only one data set per file?  Or several? Or does it vary?  What have you tried?  How did its output differ from what was expected or intended?

Comment: I updated the question, check again.

Comment: So it's always three lines per `user.conf`? Is whitespace allowed in those values?

Comment: There are several lines, but I need to look for just those results. They have no blank spaces, just a line break.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another variant:

```
awk -F'=' '
  BEGIN{ print "USER | PACKAGE | CREATOR" }
  $1=="username" || $1=="package" || $1=="creator"{
    printf $2 (++cnt%3 ? " - " : RS)
  }
' /usr/local/users/*/user.conf | column -t
```

---

**Edit**
This sorts the table by package and allows a different order of the three elements in the `user.conf` files:

```
{
  echo "USER | PACKAGE | CREATOR" 
  awk -F'=' '
    $1=="username"{ a[0]=$2 } 
    $1=="package" { a[1]=$2 }
    $1=="creator" { a[2]=$2 }
    0 in a && 1 in a && 2 in a{
      print a[0] " - " a[1] " - " a[2]
      delete a
    }
  ' /usr/local/users/*/user.conf | sort -k3,3
} | column -t
```

Comment: nice golfed !!!

Comment: @Freddy This is perfect, is it possible to order in alphabetical order following the values of "package"?

Comment: Oh, and it looks like he reversed the username and creator results.

Comment: See my edit, hope it works now.

Comment: I am speechless, that was incredible! It worked perfectly, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Given

```
$ head user?.conf
==> user1.conf <==
username=test1
package=basic1
creator=admin1

==> user2.conf <==
username=test2
package=basic2
creator=admin2

==> user3.conf <==
username=test3
package=basic3
creator=admin3
```

then using [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/)

```
$ mlr --ixtab --ips = --opprint cat user?.conf 
username package creator
test1    basic1  admin1
test2    basic2  admin2
test3    basic3  admin3
```

If you want to change the field names as well, then

```
$ mlr --ixtab --ips = --opprint rename "username,USER,package,PACKAGE,creator,CREATOR" then cat user?.conf 
USER  PACKAGE CREATOR
test1 basic1  admin1
test2 basic2  admin2
test3 basic3  admin3
```